# How to Return Byte Arrays from C# COM DLL to VB6/VBA client

Tags: c#, vba, com, vb6, com-interop

I have a C# library that I'm exposing to VBA/VB6 via COM.  I'm able to call functions and pass parameters fine for the most part, but when calling a function that has a **byte array** as an out param, I get an error "run-time error -2146233079, method 'yyy' of object 'xxx' failed".  Initially, I was getting a crash, then I realized I wasn't allocating my byte array in VB.  Once I did that the function would work, but only if I didn't set the out value.

If I remove my out param (or switch it to a ref, but don't set it in C#), the function calls and works just fine.  I have several functions with this kind of signature (several ints, a byte array in, and one **or more** byte arrays out), so I was trying not to use some sort of setter/getter workaround.

This function works-

```
public int NoOuts(int x, int y, ref byte[] msgId){}
```

These variations error if I try to set/change the sn out/ref value (I've tried multiple combinations of In, Out, ref, MarshalAs, etc.)-

```
public int OneOut(int x, int y, ref byte[] msgId, [Out] out byte[] sn){}
public int OneOut(int x, int y, ref byte[] msgId, ref byte[] sn){}
public int OneOut(int x, int y, ref byte[] msgId, [Out] ref byte[] sn){}
public int OneOut(int x, int y, ref byte[] msgId, [[Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_UI1)] out byte[] sn){}
'// Even tried it with an object
public int OneOut(int x, int y, ref byte[] msgId, [Out] out object nonce){}
```

Here's my VB6 test code (I also need it to work in VBA)-

```
    Dim i as Long
    Dim msg(7) as Byte
Dim sn(7) as Byte

For i = 0 To UBound(mesa)
    msg(i) = i * 2
Next

i = api.OneOut(5, 4, 3, 2, msg(), sn())
```

I am able to verify that the values for msg are useable in my C# function.  I'm also able to pass and change strings back and forth.

I posted a previous question along the same lines, but it was mainly about passing values into C#, not returning them.  [How to Pass Byte Arrays as UDT Properties from VB6/VBA to C# COM DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185159/)

These two posts are about something similar, but I couldn't get either method to work-

[Accepting a Byte array, vb6 to C# interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356418/)

[Return byte array from C# to VBScript via COM interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978861/)

Comment: A paremeter needs to be `ref byte[]` for VB to recognise it as a parameter/data type that it can handle. Simple as that.

Comment: @Deanna - As in my second declare where it's `public int OneOut(int x, int y, ref byte[] msgId, ref byte[] sn){}`?  It works, it just won't let me change it in the C# code.